# VS2013 : passing iterator to a function that takes pointer (migrating VS2010 to VS2013)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code, when I compile it in VS2010, compilation goes through and everything works fine.

```
AA.h

class AA
{
    int i;
public:
    AA()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    void setA(AA *a)
    {
        i = a->geti();
    }

    int geti()
    {
        return i;
    }
    void seti(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }

};
```

**Source.cpp**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "AA.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    AA a1;
    AA a2;
    AA a3;
    a1.seti(1);
    a2.seti(2);
    a3.seti(3);
    vector<AA> aList;

aList.push_back(a1);
aList.push_back(a2);
aList.push_back(a3);

for (vector<AA>::iterator itr = aList.begin();
    itr != aList.end(); itr++)
{
    AA aa;
    aa.setA(itr); // Compiler error on VS2013
    cout << aa.geti();
}

return 0;
}
```

But compiling the same code in VS2013 gives me the following compilation error:

> Source.cpp(52): error C2664: 'void AA::setA(AA *)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from
>   'std::_Vector_iterator>>' to
>   'AA *' 1> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can
>   perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Simple straight forward fix for this will be to explicitly de-reference the iterator and passing to the set function like this:

```
for (vector<AA>::iterator itr = aList.begin();
        itr != aList.end(); itr++)
    {
        AA aa;
        aa.setA(&*itr); // No error
        cout << aa.geti();
    }
```

But problem here is that we have similar code in thousands of source files and making the change in all the files will be time consuming and is not practically possible.

Can someone please tell me is there is anyway of solving this without changing all the files? Something that we can do in AA.h to take care of this?

Comment: Well, it is pay-back time for using code that assumes iterators are implemented as pointers. You should ask whoever wrote the 1000s of lines of code to fix it.

Comment: Iterator is an abstraction for accessing container elements. I do not find any logical reason for using iterator as pointer. Even if iterator is implemented in terms of pointer, it is NOT the pointer.

Comment: @RakibulHasan Outside of the fact the standards committee went above and beyond the call of duty to model their *behavior* as close to pointers as possible, I concur. Regardless, they should never be assumed to *be* pointers, just *act* like them (most of the time, anyway). Doing so will find one in... well... the not-so-happy place the OP is right now. It was a nuub mistake, one that is going to hurt for awhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use templates for the code that currently expects pointers:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void setA(Iterator a)
{
    i = a->geti();
}
```

The only drawback is that it will accept anything for which a call to a `geti()` method via a de-reference `->` returning something that can be assigned to an `int` is valid. But there are tricks you can play with [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to restrict this to class `AA`.

Comment: Throw enough SFINAE on that thing and you may be able to tighten it down a bit. Nice answer. +1

Comment: @WhozCraig Too right. I won't add a SFINAE fix, but I added a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
struct AsPointer {
  T* p;
  operator T*() const { return p; }
  T* operator->() const { return p; }
  T& operator*() const { return *p; }
  explicit operator bool() const { return p; }
  AsPointer():p(nullptr) {}
  AsPointer(AsPointer const&)=default;
  AsPointer(AsPointer&)=default;
  AsPointer(AsPointer const&&)=default;
  AsPointer(AsPointer&&)=default;
  // sfinae may not work here, but at least you get an error:
  template<typename U,typename=typename std::iterator_traits<typename std::decay<U>::type>::iterator_category>
  AsPointer(U&& u):p(&*u) {}
  template<typename U>
  AsPointer(U* u):p(u) {}
  AsPointer(std::nullptr_t):p(nullptr) {}
};
```

is a `template` pseudo-pointer that can be treated much like a pointer, but can also be implicitly converted from any `iterator`.  When you find an error, you can replace the `foo*` in the interface with `AsPointer<foo>` and hopefully things will go well.

If you pass `NULL` to the above `AsPointer`, it will probably complain -- change it to `nullptr`.  But other than that it might solve all your call-site problems with one interface change.

Me, I'd just sweep the call-sites.

Note that a `const int*` becomes a `AsPointer<const int>` not a `const AsPointer<int>`.

Comment: +.5 for the stricter general workaroud, +.5 for "sweeping the call sites" `:-)`